# setting reply-to in sendmail.mc

Tags: configuration, sendmail, forwarding

I'm using sendmail to send Mails from PHP and also forward some mails addressed to the server to a list of external mail-providers. The forwarding is done via an entry in /etc/mail/virtusertable:

```
test@domain.com testuser
```

In my /etc/aliases I include the mail list file:

```
testuser: ":include:/home/mail-list"
```

This setup works so far but I wanted to ask how it is possible to change the Reply-To Header of mails sent to the virtual user `testuser` via sendmail.mc? And if not is there another way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using some filtering e.g. via procmail script?  It will help to filter out spam based on "email list specific bayes".  It will allow you to add/replace any headers you like.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to set Reply-To is to do it in the MUA (PHP in your case), not in the MTA.

Example:

```
$to = 'bla@bla.com';
$subject = 'bla';
$message = 'bla';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

If you insist on rewriting addresses through sendmail, you shall use genericstable (see http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html#genericstable)

- Add the following lines to sendmail.mc and recompile it:

  `GENERICS_DOMAIN('name.of.localhost')dnl`

  `` FEATURE(`genericstable')dnl ``
- create a map in /etc/genericstable to translate
  outgoing addresses. The file looks like this:

localuser        newuser@newdomain

- Convert the map to a hash db file by typing `makemap hash
  /etc/genericstable.db < genericstable`

Comment: I may not have been very clear about this in my original post: The mails I'm forwarding are not sent by php but instead com from an external mail provider to the sendmail MTA.

Comment: updated answer with alternative solutions based on genericstable